# an exercise regarding sums

Tags: real-analysis

We know that for $a=1$, we have $D(1,b;c)=s(b,c)=\sum_{n \pmod c} ((\frac{n}{c}))((\frac{bn}{c}))$.

I was trying to prove the following property for coprime $b$, $c$,  ,that
$s(b,c)=\frac{-c}{4\pi^2}\sum_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{1}{x(bx+cy)}$, where the sum is taken over all $x$ and $y$ such that the denominator does not vanish.

I was thinking on applying the above property to prove this, but that seemed unfruitful. Any ideas or detailed pointers will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The corresponding post on [math.se]: [A result related to the properties of Dedekind Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233882).

Comment: How do you know the equality you're trying to prove is true?

Comment: Next time, please ask a question. Otherwise, how are we supposed to answer it?

Comment: What does it mean that your post starts with "We *also* …"?

Comment: Note that OP has edited out large chunks of the original post (which did ask a question, and didn't start with "We also").

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

Your sum is not absolutely summable, but if you first sum on $y$ and use $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}1/(x+n)=\pi\cot(\pi x)$ (symmetrical sum) you get
$$\frac{\pi}{c}\sum_x\frac{\cot(\pi bx/c)}x=\frac{\pi}{c}\sum_{n=1}^{c-1}\cot(\pi bn/c)\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}\frac{1}{mc+n}=\frac{\pi^2}{c^2}\sum_{n=1}^{c-1}\cot(\pi bn/c)\cot(\pi n/c)$$
using again the above formula for $\cot$, and you obtain your Dedekind sum.